# Firefox extension get tab index

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(event.target);
```

How I can take index of this tab?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Array.slice(getBrowser().tabs).indexOf(aTab)`